# detect #div when part of it scrolled into viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already have this which works great:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

This detects when an ENTIRE #div is in the viewport. However, I cannot figure out how to alter this so that the code detects the #div when it is only PARTLY in the viewport. Can you help me? For you guys, this is probably super simple... Thanks! I have tried to enter pixel-values but I mess it up every time!

Comment: Add small 0x0 element to begin of the #div and watch its position

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this:

```
return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
```

with this:

```
return (docViewBottom >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom);
```

and `isScrolledIntoView` function will return true as soon as element is in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without using jquery. We can get a bounding box that surrounds the element in question, and then check if the top or bottom of that box are between the top and bottom of our viewport!

```js
// Assuming elem is an actual element, not a string selector
// You can use jquery or standard dom functions like querySelector to find the element if it's a selector

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
   const box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
   const topInside = (box.top > 0 && box.top < window.innerHeight)
   const bottomInside = (box.bottom > 0 && box.bottom < window.innerHeight)
   return topInside || bottomInside
}
```